# Permission denied mv /usr/bin

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal, mv

I am trying to rename a file, but it doesn't work.

FYI I am in /usr/bin

```
(input) mv python pythonOLD
(output) mv: rename python to pythonOLD: Operation not permitted
```

When I try sudo:

```
(input) sudo mv python pythonOLD
Password:
(output) mv: rename python to pythonOLD: Operation not permitted
```

any sugguestions?

Comment: I'm not here to question your motives, but generally it's not recommended to rename system files like that. One case you might worry about is existing programs whose depend on knowing where a binary is, and renaming it like that could break more than one thing in a way that would be hard to detect.

Comment: If you want the command "python" to refer to a newer version, I might suggest adding something like `alias python="/path/to/desired/python/binary"` in your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/`.whatever-shell-you-use-rc`, and in your everyday command line use this will let you just type "python" to use the desired version.

Comment: I'm not trying to use python3 when 'python' is declared, I want to use it when I use a ./ before the filename

Comment: Ah, I see. If you want python3 to be used when using `./filename` to execute the program, then you need to put a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of `filename`. You would do so by inserting a new line at the top containing `#!/path/to/python3`. This will tell the machine to execute that file using whatever binary is located at `/path/to/python3`.

Comment: mppombo5 I already figured out how to change my main python language, which was my main goal ind doing all this. But I am having a problem with some "error importing: PycURL lib" stuff. I have made another post about it, if you could help out with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged macOS, so I'm guessing you're using Catalina. On Catalina, Apple split the disk into two partitions, a read-only system partition, and a user data writable partition. [Here's an answer with more details.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367159/269453) So you actually can't mess with /usr/bin.

The generally recommended solution is to leave system python2.7 alone, and as another user stated, add an another version of Python to your path ahead of it.

Comment: Actually, modifying /bin has been forbidden by [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) since El Capitan. The dual-partition format used by Catalina just reinforces and extends that protection.

Comment: (Sorry, I don't know too much about coding) And how do I actually change the path of a file? Just go into the bash_profile and change $PATH?

Comment: Just changing the path would work, and you can look up how to do that. But I used [Brew](https://brew.sh) to install python3, which lives on the path as `python3`, and then use that.